# Unable to update file details entries in mysql db using Laminas and Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, zend-framework3, laminas

I'm able to add file details in database but not able to update it.

I am able to add file details entries, but when i try to update only the file that i am updating is moved to the storage folder. My update manager doesn't show any errors and doesn't update the file details in database.

**this is my file form**

```
protected function addElements() 
{
    // Add "name" field
    $this->add([           
        'type'  => 'file',
        'name' => 'image',
        'attributes' => [
            'id' => 'image'
        ],
        'options' => [
            'label' => 'ImageFile',
        ],
    ]);
    
   
                    
    // Add the Submit button
    $this->add([
        'type'  => 'submit',
        'name' => 'submit',
        'attributes' => [                
            'value' => 'Add Image File',
            'id' => 'submit',
        ],
    ]);
    
    // Add the CSRF field
    $this->add([
        'type' => 'csrf',
        'name' => 'csrf',
        'options' => [
            'csrf_options' => [
            'timeout' => 600
            ]
        ],
    ]);
}

public function addInputFilter()
{
    $inputFilter = new InputFilter\InputFilter();

    // File Input
    $fileInput = new InputFilter\FileInput('image');
    $fileInput->setRequired(true);
   
    $inputFilter->add($fileInput);

    $this->setInputFilter($inputFilter);
}
```

}

**this is the update image manager**

```
public function updateImage($name, $size)
{
$images = new Images();
$images->setName($name);
$images->setSize($size);                

// Apply changes to database.
$this->entityManager->flush();

}
```

**and this is my controller**

```
public function editAction()
{
    
    $id = (int)$this->params()->fromRoute('id', -1);
    if ($id<1) {
        $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(404);
        return;
    }
    
    $image = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Images::class)
            ->find($id);
    
    if ($image == null) {
        $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(404);
        return;
    }
    // Create form
    $form = new ImageUploadForm('update', $this->entityManager);
   $request = $this->getRequest();
   if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        
        $data = array_merge_recursive(
            $request->getPost()->toArray(),
            $request->getFiles()->toArray()
        );            
        
        $form->setData($data);
        
        
        if($form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            $imgtmp = $data["image"]["tmp_name"];
            
            $name = $data["image"]["name"];
            $size = $data["image"]["size"];
            $filepath = $this->_dir.$name;
            move_uploaded_file($imgtmp, $filepath);
            
            $this->achimotaImagesManager->updateImage($name, $size);
            
            var_dump($name, $size);
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('images', ['action'=>'index']);
        }
    }
    
    return new ViewModel([
        'form' => $form,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Please do not write anymore something like `$image = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Images::class)->find($id);` inside your Controller. Please don't. It's bad, very bad. Do not put the mess in something so strong that Zend Framework / Laminas (since January 2020).

Comment: And do not add a FileInputFilter inside your form class. Separate them. You will not put the mess in.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not create a new object**

If you update an Images entity (consider naming it Image if it is one image), you should not create a new one. Hand over the $image you need to update:

```
public function updateImage($image, $name, $size){
    $image->setName($name);
    $image->setSize($size);
    ...
}
```

**Persist before flush**

You need to persist the entity before you flush.

```
$this->entityManager->persist($image);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

**Organize the code nicer**

1. Do not inject entity manager in your controller. Inject rather a service through a factory, which handles all features of your Image entity. (ImageService.php)
2. Do not inject entity manager into your ImageService neither. Create a ImageMapper service, inject that into your ImageService. Create all Doctrine-related features in this Mapper. This has this advantage: Doctrin specific functionality is only in your Mapper files. Should you need to use another solution to store data, you only need to replace the Mapper files, providing the Service with the same interface.

*Controller*

```
public function editAction()
{
    ...
    $this->serviceImage->update($image,$name,$size);
    ...
}
```

*Service - ImageService.php*

```
public function update($image,$name,$size)
{
    $image->setName($name);
    $image->setSize($size);
    $this->mapperImage->save($image);
}
```

*Mapper - ImageMapper.php*

```
public function save($image)
{
    $this->managerEntity->persist($image);
    $this->managerEntity->flush();
}
```

Consider adding rich comments and typehints to the arguments and return value of the functions.

**Moreover**

1. The form should not be created in your controller. Put that code in your ImageService too. And consider inject form into the service. (Make sure you define the form for the factory in the getFormElementConfig()! This is more advance stuff, if you do not test with phpunit, you might not bother creating form as a service, hovever it leads to a very organized codebase.)
2. var_dump($name, $size) has no place in your controller. (If this is for debug purposes, it is OK, but use rather something like XDebug with a compatible IDE - PHPStorm is far the best one.)
3. This line is not so easy to understand: $filepath = $this->_dir.$name; Maybe:

   $filePath = _dir . $name;
4. Naming convention: look for camelCase.